# Keep getting the Py4JError when working with the pyspark dataframe

Tags: postgresql, docker, pyspark

I have a docker container up and running in vs code. With pyspark I connect to a postgres database on my local machine:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .config("spark.jars", "/opt/spark/jars/postgresql-42.2.5.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()
    
df = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://host.docker.internal:5432/postgres") \
    .option("dbtable", "chicago_crime") \
    .option("user", "postgres") \
    .option("password", "postgres") \
    .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver") \
    .load()

type(df)
```

Output:
**pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame**

Example code of what works:

```
df.printSchema()
df.select('ogc_fid').show() #(Raises a Py4JJavaError sometimes)
```

Example code of what does not work:

```
df.show(1) # Py4JJavaError and ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
    [... skipping hidden 1 frame]

Cell In[2], line 1
----> 1 df.show(1)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py:606, in DataFrame.show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    605 if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
--> 606     print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
    607 else:

File /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py:1321, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1320 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1321 return_value = get_return_value(
   1322     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1324 for temp_arg in temp_args:

File /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py:190, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    189 try:
--> 190     return f(*a, **kw)
    191 except Py4JJavaError as e:

File /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
...
--> 438 self.socket.connect((self.java_address, self.java_port))
    439 self.stream = self.socket.makefile("rb")
    440 self.is_connected = True

ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Anyone knows what this Py4JJavaError is? And how to overcome it?

Answer (score 1):

PySpark is just a Wrapper around the actual implementation of Spark, which is written in Scala. Py4J enables you to communicate with the JVM process in Python.

That means the Py4JJavaError is only an abstraction, it tells you that the JVM process threw an Exception.

The real error is `ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused`.
I assume the error is caused while connecting to your Postgres instance.